# Using permissions without repeating code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that requires the user to be a owner or an admin. Some commands are only available to owners and not admins but owners can also run admin commands.

I find that I'm just repeating the same code for both parts. Is there a way to consolidate this so I don't violate the rule of repeating myself?

Here's a general scheme of what I have:

```
request(checkPermissionRequest, function (error, response, body) {
    // Determine who is allowed to run the script
    switch (body[0].permission) {
        // Owner
        case 0:
            if (isOwner(user)) {
            // Script code
            }
            break;
        // Admin
        case 1:
            if (isOwner(user) || isAdmin(user)) {
                // Script code
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

### UPDATE

I can see how my above explanation has caused some confusion so I'll try to attempt to clear it up. There are multiple available scripts and some are for owner and some for admins (which can also be run by owner). These permissions are saved in a database and I get it by making a request. This is why I can't just set things for owners and things for admins and owners because I don't know what permission the script is until I get the result from the database. These permissions are set by the owners and I cannot keep track of them. I modified the code to try to show more clarity.

Comment: You don't mention whether this is client-side or server-side logic, but it's important to mention that if it's client-side, you're not going to have a lot of success doing permissions like this. If you've sent a piece of script down to the browser, then any user can see that script and can manually execute it, whether `isOwner(user)` says they should be able to or not.

Comment: @SamHanley Just because it's tagged javascript, it should not be assumed it's client-side :) But true statement, let's wait for OP to verify :)

Comment: That's true, I guess. I just tend to assume that basic JavaScript questions are client-side unless stated to be otherwise. I edited my comment to reflect that perhaps premature assumption, though. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you check for 0 and 1 and then check the user again?

Comment: Not sure why the if is a bad repeating yourself....

Comment: @SamHanley Sorry this is in node I didn't tag it as such because I didn't think it had relevance but after your comment I see the point.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy, thanks for providing more clarity! So just to confirm my understanding -- basically, scripts are tagged with either a 0 or a 1, 0 meaning that only an owner can run them and a 1 meaning that an admin or owner can? If so, I'll edit my answer to suggest a new approach.

Comment: @SamHanley Yes that's correct. The script does the same thing but the owner chooses if only he can run it or if the admin can run it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you've designed your scripts, your permissions levels are represented by integers. Let's use that to our advantage.

Let's define a helper function like this:

```
function getUserPermissions(user) {
    if(isOwner(user) return 0;
    if(isAdmin(user) return 1;
    return 2; // or some arbitrarily high value- heck, even Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
}
```

Then, instead of needing a switch and a bunch of if statements, you can simply do something like this:

```
request(checkPermissionRequest, function (error, response, body) {
    // Determine who is allowed to run the script
    if(getUserPermissions(user) < parseInt(body[0].permission) {
        // do the script
    }
});
```

If following this pattern, you could also consider switching the 0 and 1, if you're able, so that a higher numeric value indicates a higher level of permissions -- if only for the sake of readability, as it would allow a -1 value to indicate someone with no permissions. In that case, you would want to change the if condition to check for `getUserPermissions(user) > parseInt(body[0].permission` rather than `<`.

On the other hand, if you stay with the slightly less readable `<` option, that allows for adding other levels of permission with less access than admin as `3` and so on, without having to increment the existing Owner and Admin levels.

Comment: I edited my question to provide more clarity, I hope it can help.

Comment: I rewrote my answer with a new suggestion based on your new details. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the if, and just exclude 'admin' from the first chunk of data.

```
if (isOwner(user) || isAdmin(user)) { 
    //some permissions for both
    if(isOwner(user)) { 
        //more permissions just for owner 
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work -- admin users who aren't owners would never hit the second `if`.

Comment: Ooh I didn't think straight - I'll come back to this.

Comment: Update - should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isOwner(user) || (isAdmin(user) && script.permission == 1)) {
    // Script code
}
```